# Jquery Form Submit function not working

Tags: jquery, html, form-submit

**FOUND THE SOLUTION:**

I had to encapsulate the function in another function. This is because it clashes with other Js libraries that i had on my html file.

Cheers everyone!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        ( function($) {
            // we can now rely on $ within the safety of our “bodyguard” function
            $(document).ready( function() { alert("nyah nyah! I’m able to use '$'!!!!");  
                            $("#keywordForm").submit(function(e) { alert('asshole');})});
        } ) ( jQuery );
```

Previous Question

My submit button doesn't do anything even after i've bind the form to jquery.

No alert messages are displayed meaning to say it did not even go into that function.

I'm up in arms over this issue. :(

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $("form").submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault()
                alert("sometext"); 
                return false;
                updateKeywordSubscribed(e); 
            });
        });
        function updateKeywordSubscribed(e, keywords) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var option_form = jQuery(e.target);
            $.ajax({
                url : option_form.attr('action'),
                type : option_form.attr('method'),
                data : option_form.serialize(),
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(response) {
                        console.log(response)
                        var result = response.data
                        if(result == 'False')
                            { alert('Failed')}
                        alert('some text');
            error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        // log ajax errors
                    }
            });
        }

    <!--function DoTheCheck() { {% for price in price_list %}
                    if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == {{ price.no_of_keywords }}) 
                        { alert('Price to pay is $' + {{ price.price_of_each_keyword }} + '.0'); }
                {% endfor %}
                }-->

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- header -->
        <div id="header-wrap">
            <div id="header">
                <a name="top"></a>
                <h1 id="logo-text"><a href="/" title=""style="padding-left:32px; top: 80px;">Rosebud</a></h1>
                <p id="slogan"style="padding-left:32px;letter-spacing:0px;">
                    Your brand on the web...
                </p>
                <div  id="nav" style="padding-top: 15px;">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/topic/">Topic</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/opinion/">Opinion</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/statistics/">Statistics</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/realtime/">Realtime</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/">Support</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/about/">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="current">
                            <a href="/profile/">My Profile</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <p id="auth" style="margin: 0px;">
                    <a href="/">Welcome {{ user.username }} &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="/accounts/logout">Log Out</a>
                </p>
                {% else %}
                <p id="auth" style="margin: 0px;">
                    <a href="/accounts/login/">Log In &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="/accounts/register/">Register</a>
                </p>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of Header -->
        <div id="content-wrap">
            <!-- content -->
            <div id="content-home">
                <br />
                {% block content %} <h2 style="margin: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;">Profile Page</h2>
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <p id="auth" style="margin: 0px;">
                    {% for userprofile in object_list %}
                    {% if userprofile.username = user.username %}
                    <table style="margin: 0px; width: 600px; border: 0;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 250px; border: 0;"><label for="first_name">First Name:</label></td>
                                <td style="border: 0;">{{ userprofile.first_name }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="border: 0;"><label for="last_name">Last Name: </label></td>
                                <td style="border: 0;">{{ userprofile.last_name }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="border: 0;"><label for="email">Email: </label></td>
                                <td style="border: 0;">{{ userprofile.email }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="border: 0;"><label for="username">Username: </label></td>
                                <td style="border: 0;">{{ userprofile.username }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="border: 0;"><label for="keywords">Keywords currently subscribed to: </label></td>
                                <td style="border: 0;">{{ userprofile.keywords_subscribed }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <input type="button" name = "submit" id="keywordBtn" value="Click to refresh list of keywords subscribed" action="/refresh_list/" />
                                <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME="username" Value = {{ userprofile.username }} >
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <br />
                     <h3 style="margin: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;">Click the checkboxes for more subscriptions</h3>
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                    {% for keyword in keyword_list %}
                                        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"3" %}
                                                <tr>
                                        {% endif %}
                                        <td>
                                            {% if keyword.keyword_name == userprofile.keywords_subscribed  %}
                                                <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" name="keywords" value="keywords"/>
                                            {% else %}
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="keywords"  />
                                            {% endif %}
                                            {{keyword.keyword_name}}
                                            </td>
                                        {% if forloop.counter|add:"1"|divisibleby:"3" %}
                                                </tr>
                                        {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </tbody>
                            </table>                    
                    <br />
                    <h3 style="margin: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;">Price of subscriptions</h3>
                    <div id = "subscription"></div>
                    <input type="button" value="Amount to pay!" onclick="DoTheCheck()">
                    <br />
                    </br>
                    <form id="keywordForm" method="post"> <!--action="/keyword_subscribe/"--> 
                    <P>Keyword: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="keyword_input" Value = "Enter a new Keyword" class = 'hint'><BR><BR>
                    <!--<INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME="name_input" Value = {{ userprofile.username }} >-->
                    <INPUT TYPE="submit" Value="Crawl" name="crawl">
                    </P>
                    </form>
```

And here's the Jquery part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $("#keywordForm").submit(function(e) {
                alert("sometext"); 
                return false;
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JUST FOUND it... You are missing `},` in the code so your javascript is invalid.

**Fixed JavaScript:**

```
function updateKeywordSubscribed(e, keywords) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var option_form = jQuery(e.target);
    $.ajax({
        url: option_form.attr('action'),
        type: option_form.attr('method'),
        data: option_form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            var result = response.data;
            if (result == 'False') {
                alert('Failed');
            }
            alert('some text');
        }, // <================= That was missing!  ****************************
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            // log ajax errors
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("sometext");
        updateKeywordSubscribed(e);
        return false;
    });
});​
```

By the way you used the function `updateKeywordSubscribed` before it was declared, and put it after return statment, so my code should fix all of those problems.

Comment: thanks gdron! yours was a good answer. but i found the solution. see the top @gdoron

Comment: @StanwinSiow. You should upvote good answers... and you should post an answer if you found one, not edit the question. Glad you managed to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `updateKeywordSubscribed(e);` after you `return false;` so it never actually calls your function

Comment: yes but that's the later part. I want it to display an alert first. i can't get it to display an alert so there's no point debugging the rest

Comment: you coould've just used jquery noConflict() which you should always use if you include multiple js librarrys using the $ variable

Answer (score 0):

You're redeclared the form submit event twice, but this should work anyway.

Delete this code

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     $("form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        alert("sometext"); 
        return false;
        updateKeywordSubscribed(e); 
     });
});
```

Look it http://jsfiddle.net/KcpKk/

Comment: then isn't that my jquery code? this is the link to my html http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11787778/userprofile_list.html

Comment: it isn't work. css and js not found. please fix to test it @StanwinSiow